# Could not load file or assembly 'AWS.Logger.Core'

Tags: amazon-web-services, logging, nlog

I have created a new project and added Nlog.AWS.Logger.i have created AWSTarget object using latest version of 'AWS.Logger.Core' which is 1.3.1.0, and when i run it, it gives me the following error. Can anyone help?

Could not load file or assembly 'AWS.Logger.Core, Version=1.3.1.0'

```
using NLog.AWS.Logger;

 public ActionResult Index()
    {
        AWSTarget objtarget = new AWSTarget();
        return View();
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

I also ran into this problem, there seems to be a problem with 1.3.1.0.

The solution for me was to downgrade to version 1.3.0.0 (AWS.Logger.Core).

Comment: This did work for me too. 1.3.0.0 working, changing nuget to 1.3.1.0 breaks.